Поиск одинаковых дат в дублях
Получил DataFrame с дубликатами:



Дата
Заявка
Ответственный




05.06.2024
3450
Иванов


12.07.2024
3450
Иванов


08.05.2024
1578
Иванов


08.05.2024
1578
Иванов


05.06.2024
3450
Власов


12.07.2024
3450
Власов


10.11.2024
2190
Егоров


10.11.2024
2190
Егоров



Как мне получить строки где даты одинаковы?



Дата
Заявка
Ответственный




08.05.2024
1578
Иванов


08.05.2024
1578
Иванов


10.11.2024
2190
Егоров


10.11.2024
2190
Егоров



И оставить только по 1 строке?



Дата
Заявка
Ответственный




08.05.2024
1578
Иванов


10.11.2024
2190
Егоров




Легко:
df_dup = df[df.duplicated()]

Если дубликаты нужно считать не по всем полям, и нужно оставить не первую запись, а последнюю, можно сделать так:
subset=('Заявка', 'Ответственный')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t')
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=subset)]
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=subset, keep='last')
df


Спасибо!
А что делать с ситуацией, когда у меня 1 заявка, но 4 строки, где 2 даты это 08.05.2024 и 10.11.2024. У меня остается по одной заявке от 08.05 и 10.11, но нужно оставить только более свежую от 10.11?

Дополнил ответ.
